# Tensorflow.image.decode_jpeg shifts values while decoding image TFRecord data

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm storing a variable numbers of jpg frames per example into TFRecord using [SequenceExample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto):

```
tf.compat.as_bytes(cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1].tobytes()))
```

Then I parse these frames back by using:

```
images = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.decode_jpeg(x, channels=3), sequence_features['frames'], dtype=tf.uint8)
```

But the image values are somehow shifted:

[image]

When I just parse the raw byte string and then decode it with opencv later, the picture looks normal:

```
for img in images:
  img = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8)
  img = cv2.imdecode(img, 1)
```

[image]

More complete example:

```
def write(videos, tfr_path):
  with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfr_path) as writer:
    for video in videos:
      label = get_label()
      frames = []
        for frame in video:
          frames.append(tf.compat.as_bytes(cv2.imencode(".jpg", prec_img)[1].tobytes()))

      feature_list = {
                  'label': (_float_list_feature_list(label),),
                  'frames': _bytes_feature_list(encoded_frames)
              }
      feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list=feature_list)

      example = tf.train.SequenceExample(feature_lists=feature_lists, context=None)
      writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def _parse_tfr_data(example, size):
  sequence_features = {
      'label': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([size], dtype=tf.float32),
      'frames': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string)
  }

  features, sequence_features = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(example, context_features=None,
                                                             sequence_features=sequence_features)

  images = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.decode_jpeg(x, channels=3), sequence_features['frames'], dtype=tf.uint8)
  label = sequence_features['label']

  return images, label
```

Comment: Looks like red and blue channels are swapped. OpenCV `imread`/`imwrite`/`imencode`/`imdecode` work with BGR. Are you sure that's also the case with tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek)! tf.image.decode_jpeg uses RGB cv2.imencode BGR, so swapping it beforehand worked.